# How can I delete an XMLSchemaReference when using WordProcessingDocument?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, wordprocessingml

I want to delete an XMLSchemaReference from a Word document. When running VBA code, this is simple:

```
ActiveDocument.XMLSchemaReferences("ActionsPane3").Delete
```

When using the ThisDocument class in a VSTO, this is also simple with C#:

```
Globals.ThisDocument.XMLSchemaReferences["ActionsPane3"].Delete();
```

However, when using a instance of WordProcessingDocument (in a normal windows application), I do not know how to perform the same action. Any idea of how I should write my C# code?

Comment: The usual way to discover this is to have the document both with and without the ActionsPane. Use the Compare functionality in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to discover the difference in the underlying XML as well as the code required to create the second document from the first.

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this, the best thing you can do is download the [Open XML SDK productivity tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) and compare the documents you made before and after you've made the change. When I use VSTO to add an actionspane and I explore the package in the tool I notice this:

[image]

Then I remove the actionspane with the code you gave:

```
Globals.ThisDocument.XMLSchemaReferences["ActionsPane3"].Delete();
this.Save();
```

If we look at the package in the tool now we have the following (please do notice the awesome free-hand writing):

[image]

Now that we have identified what needs to be removed we can start working with the open xml sdk (`using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging` to open the file and `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing` to modify it). It's always convenient to keep the document open in the tool to be able to use the tree structure to build up the code. First I write the code to open and save the document:

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\WorkSpace\test\WordTest.docx");

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
   stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
   using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
   {
       //Logic here
   }

   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\WorkSpace\test\WordTest_modified.docx", 
          FileMode.Create))
   {
      stream.WriteTo(fs);
   }
}
```

To remove the `AttachedSchema` you need the following code:

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart
                    .Settings
                    .GetFirstChild<AttachedSchema>()
                    .Remove();
```

As you see it's very convenient to write this with the tree structure next to you. To remove the `SchemaReference` you will need this code:

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.CustomXmlParts.First()
                    .CustomXmlPropertiesPart
                    .DataStoreItem
                    .SchemaReferences
                    .FirstChild
                    .Remove();
```

And there you go, the same as if you would have removed it in the VSTO application.

**Edit:** If I execute the following line to remove all the `/docProps/custom.xml` the action pane is gone:

```
doc.CustomFilePropertiesPart.Properties.RemoveAllChildren();
```

I can't really test if that's the expected behavior for you because I use a test document (no notable change in size), but seeing now my action pane is gone, it might be what you're looking for (the properties contain a reference to my local vsto file). I wish microsoft would document this kind of stuff a little better.

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me a bit further but is not a full solution yet. I see my .docx shrinked 1 KB  instead of 105 KB (what happens when running the VBA code or VSTO application). After opening the document, the actions pane is still there. Is there something additional that should be done? This is probably almost the full solution.

Comment: @Daan That's what I found weird, when I used your code to remove the reference to the actionpane, I also still had it. Is there perhaps more code in the vsto application? Probably the custom xml part will have to be removed all together.

Comment: No, there is nothing more. In addition. When running a single line of VBA-code (see above) I also get the effect I need. However, I do not get the right effect in my normal windows application using WordprocessingDocument. Your code looks nice and it is expected to work but unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm I'll test tomorrow what happens if I just delete the customxml part all together, who knows :-)

Comment: @Daan Edited answer, managed to remove the action pane for my document. Not sure if it's just hidden or if it's actually removed because I don't have a big test document like you.